# Как добавлять Inline кнопки в ряд

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Мне нужно создать игру шашки в телеграм, я хочу это сделать Inline кнопками. Я додумался просто в цикле составлять поле, но непонимаю как добовлять Inline кнопки в ряд

Answer (score 2):

пример для pytelegrambotapi:

```
kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
next = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='дальше', callback_data='next')
stop = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='стоп', callback_data='stop')
kb.add(next, stop)  # кнопки будут в один ряд, бок о бок

# кнопка = ряд
kb.add(next)
kb.add(stop)
```